# How to toggle plus to minus and vice-versa in bootstrap Accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, react-bootstrap

I am woking on `Accordion` using `react-bootstrap` I have successfully created the Accordion, Now I want to provide toggle to the each header like plus minus when it is open show - sing when it is closed show plus sign, But I am not able to handle the event

**What I have Done**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Accordion, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    { name: "mike", age: 22 },
    { name: "clive", age: 25 },
    { name: "morgan", age: 82 }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <Card>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey={index}>
              {item.name}
            </Accordion.Toggle>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={index}>
              <Card.Body>{item.age}</Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

[I am using this](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/accordion/#accordion)

[Working Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-shape-6bb16?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a custom [`Accordion.Toggle#`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/accordion/#custom-toggle) with custom `onclick` event, also use `useState` to handle the toggle event that set `+`/`-` signs:

Here is a snippet or [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-montalcini-svo7j?file=/src/App.js):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Accordion, Card, useAccordionToggle } from "react-bootstrap";

function CustomToggle({ children, eventKey, handleClick }) {
  const decoratedOnClick = useAccordionToggle(eventKey, () => {
    handleClick();
  });

  return (
    <div className="card-header" type="button" onClick={decoratedOnClick}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(0);

  const data = [
    { name: "mike", age: 22 },
    { name: "clive", age: 25 },
    { name: "morgan", age: 82 }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey={0} activeKey={activeKey}>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <Card key={index}>
            <CustomToggle
              as={Card.Header}
              eventKey={index}
              handleClick={() => {
                if (activeKey === index) {
                  setActiveKey(null);
                } else {
                  setActiveKey(index);
                }
              }}
            >
              {item.name}
              {activeKey === index ? "-" : "+"}
            </CustomToggle>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={index}>
              <Card.Body>{item.age}</Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Its there already, but here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-montalcini-svo7j?file=/src/App.js

Comment: hey I am using `<Accordion defaultActiveKey={0}>` to active first one but it shows +, the first one is always open so it should show -

Comment: And I am using this `<i className="fas fa-angle-i float-right"></i>` to show the up and down

Comment: I updated my snippet, please check, also for the icon, I will leave it to you, since it should be as simple as replacing sings -/+ with tag and class name, please accept as answer if you find my answer useful to you.

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Hey every thing is fine now, just one issue first one is always open so when I click on second one the first one gets closed but the sign do not  change from - to plus, it is same for anyone if i close any one the other one sign remains the same

Comment: I just fixed it can you check, I figured out that there is a `activekey` and `defaultkey` attributes in the API, its fixed and should work properly now without too much customization.